# Protoype/Scriptaculous Autocomplete

Tags: asp.net, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I am getting this error when trying to select a object in my autocomplete

This only comes up in IE 8, and Firefox 3.5, not IE 7 or FF 3.0

Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "An invalid or illegal string was specified"  code: "12" nsresult: "0x8053000c (NS_ERROR_DOM_SYNTAX_ERR)"  location: "http://localhost/js/prototype.js Line: 2853"]

P2N.Submission.autoSuggest.init('',
             'place-list', 
             'hiddenPlaceID', 
             '/placeSearch.ashx?cityID=&allowNewPlace=', 
             'place-search-spinner', {resultID : '' });

**Update:**
p2n is

```
var P2N = {
    returnVal: null, 
    errorMsg: null,
    initWindow: function() {
    },
    addSpinner: function(el) {
        if(!$(el).next('img.spinner'))$(el).insert({after: '<img src="/img/spinner_small.gif" alt="" class="spinner" />'})
    },
    removeSpinner: function(el) {
        var spinner = $(el).next('img.spinner');
        if (spinner != null) spinner.remove();
    }
```

autoSuggest.init I believe is prototype version 1.6, and Scriptaclous vers 1.8
While they also are loading jquery ver 1.3.2
I believe it may be a conflict in all of these, but why would it work in older browsers?

```
};
```

Comment: if it comes up in Firefox, can you run your JavaScript code through the Firebug debugger and find out what line triggers it? Then post that line and anything related to it up here so we can see it. Alternatively, if you don't want us to see your code, you could then create a simple test script that triggers the error.

It'd also be good to know what version of Prototype you're using.

Comment: Well the thing is this site is hundreds of files written originally from a 3rd Party, so I'll try to get the information needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the same problem - it's definitely a bug in prototype.js 1.6.0.x. Upgrading to 1.6.1 fixed it.